# Create an authentication path with bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, recursive-query

I have a SQL-bigquery question I’m hoping you can help me with. I’ve searched quite intensely for a week but have been unsuccessful. I have a login log file of ~1 billion records. The file has data such as:

`Time.  User.  Source computer.  Destination computer. 
 1.     U12.   C04.              C11
 2.     U14.   C09.              C14
 3.     U11.   C04.              C23
 4.     U12.   C11.              C14
 5.     U12.   C23.              C24
 6.     U14.   C09.              C14`

I need to determine all the possible authentication paths as follow:

```
User.   Authentication Path. 
U12.    C04,C11
U12.    C04,C11,C14
U12.    C23,C24
U14.    C09,C14
U11.    C04,C23
```

It looks recursive, and I tried following some examples for page paths, but couldn’t make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should be good start for you

`It looks recursive`  - indeed it is - thanks to UDF

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION path(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<s STRING, d STRING>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [], p;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){arr[i].flag = 0;}
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].flag == 0) {
      arr[i].flag = 1;
      p = arr[i].s + ',' + arr[i].d + next(p, arr[i].d);
      result.push(p);
    }
  }; return result;

  function next(p, s) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr[j].flag == 0 && arr[j].s == s) {
        arr[j].flag = 1;
        return ',' + arr[j].d + next(p, arr[j].d);
      } 
    } return '';
  }

""";
SELECT user, 
  path(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<s STRING, d STRING>(source, destination) ORDER BY time)) AS path
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
GROUP BY user
```

You can test above with dummy data from your questions as below

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION path(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<s STRING, d STRING>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = [], p;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){arr[i].flag = 0;}
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].flag == 0) {
      arr[i].flag = 1;
      p = arr[i].s + ',' + arr[i].d + next(p, arr[i].d);
      result.push(p);
    }
  }; return result;

  function next(p, s) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(arr[j].flag == 0 && arr[j].s == s) {
        arr[j].flag = 1;
        return ',' + arr[j].d + next(p, arr[j].d);
      } 
    } return '';
  }

""";
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 1 time, 'U12' user, 'C04' source, 'C11' destination UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'U14', 'C09', 'C14' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'U11', 'C04', 'C23' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'U12', 'C11', 'C14' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'U12', 'C23', 'C24' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'U14', 'C10', 'C15' 
)
SELECT user, 
  path(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<s STRING, d STRING>(source, destination) ORDER BY time)) AS path
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY MIN(time)
```

the result is as below

```sql
Row user    path     
1   U12     C04,C11,C14  
            C23,C24  
2   U14     C09,C14  
            C10,C15  
3   U11     C04,C23
```

Comment: Thanks kindly for your help. sorry for the delay, was firefighting some other issues.

Comment: I will! im still working through it to 'get it'.  Haven't use JS in my past, so stay tuned and thanks again for the input. will be back soon.